# How to add <owl:Ontology rdf:about="..."/> in Jena?

Tags: jena, owl

I am creating an ontology using apache jena. 
How do I add the following simple statement using the jena library?

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.owl"/>
```

Comment: why do you need this? You can use an `OntModel` and call [`createOntology(uri)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#createOntology-java.lang.String-) or add just an RDF triple for this. It's nothing more than `<http://example.owl> rdf:type owl:Ontology .`

Comment: I am working with a specific parser which requires this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AKSW points out correctly, method (`createOntology`) needs to be called on the model itself:

```
model.createOntology("http://example.owl");
```